# count( *) query is getting formed instead select (*) query while using Spring Data Jpa and Spring Data Rest

Tags: hibernate, rest, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have the following code in my Resource, Service and Repository of my Spring Data Jpa and Spring Data REST based application :

In Resource.java,

```
// Get User Assigned Customers  by User Id
@RequestMapping(value = "/userAssignedClientss/byUserId",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserAssignedClients>> findByUserId(@RequestParam(value="userId") Long userId,
            @RequestParam(value = "page" , required = false) Integer offset,
            @RequestParam(value = "per_page", required = false) Integer limit ) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug(" REST request to get User Assigned Clients By User Id " + userId);

        Page<UserAssignedClients> page = userAssignedClientsService.findByUserId(userId, offset, limit);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/userAssignedClientss/byUserId", offset, limit);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<UserAssignedClients>>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);        
    }
```

In my Service.java :

```
public Page<UserAssignedClients> findByUserId(Long userId, Integer offset, Integer limit) {
    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(offset, limit, Sort.Direction.ASC, "userId");
    Page<UserAssignedClients> userAssignedClientsList = userAssgClientsRepository.findByUserId(userId, pageable);
    log.debug(" - Returned userAssignedCustomersList Size " + userAssignedClientsList.getSize());

    return userAssgClientsRepository.findByUserId(userId, pageable);
}
```

In Repository.java :

```
Page<UserAssignedClients> findByUserId(Long userId, Pageable pageable);
```

I have expected the query to be formed some thing similar to `select * from user_assigned_clients where user_id = ?`

But surprisingly count(*) query is getting formed and I am empty array as response. The following is my java debugging log in eclipse.

```
[DEBUG] com.sample.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Enter: com.sample.web.rest.UserAssignedClientsResource.findByUserId() with argument[s] = [123456, 1, 10]
[DEBUG] com.sample.web.rest.UserAssignedClientsResource -  : REST request to get User Assigned Clients By User Id 123456
[DEBUG] com.sample.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Enter: com.sample.service.UserAssignedClientsService.findByUserId() with argument[s] = [123456, 1, 10]
Hibernate: select count(userassign0_.id) as col_0_0_ from user_assigned_clients userassign0_ where userassign0_.user_id=?
[DEBUG] com.sample.service.UserAssignedClientsService -  - Returned userAssignedCustomersList Size 10
Hibernate: select count(userassign0_.id) as col_0_0_ from user_assigned_clients userassign0_ where userassign0_.user_id=?
[DEBUG] com.sample.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Exit: com.sample.service.UserAssignedClientsService.findByUserId() with result = Page 1 of 1 containing UNKNOWN instances
[DEBUG] com.sample.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Exit: com.sample.web.rest.UserAssignedClientsResource.findByUserId() with result = <200 OK,[],{X-Total-Count=[1], Link=[</userAssignedClientss/byUserId?page=1&per_page=10>; rel="last",</userAssignedClientss/byUserId?page=1&per_page=10>; rel="first"]}>
```

The following is my UserAssignedClients.java fie :

```
/**
 * A UserAssignedClients.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_assigned_clients")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class UserAssignedClients implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "user_code")
    private String userCode;

    @Column(name = "client_id")
    private Long clientId;

    @Column(name = "client_code")
    private String clientCode;

    @Column(name = "client_name")
    private String clientName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserCode() {
        return userCode;
    }

    public void setUserCode(String userCode) {
        this.userCode = userCode;
    }

    public Long getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(Long clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public String getClientCode() {
        return clientCode;
    }

    public void setClientCode(String clientCode) {
        this.clientCode = clientCode;
    }

    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    public void setClientName(String clientName) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        UserAssignedClients userAssignedClients = (UserAssignedClients) o;

        if ( ! Objects.equals(id, userAssignedClients.id)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserAssignedClients{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", userId='" + userId + "'" +
                ", userCode='" + userCode + "'" +
                ", clientId='" + clientId + "'" +
                ", clientCode='" + clientCode + "'" +
                ", clientName='" + clientName + "'" +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that you are doing pagination, it makes sense that a count(*) query would be executed. Is it possible that the count is zero? In the zero case, I would not expect to see a select get executed and an empty response would be correct...

Answer (score 0):

**It is because you are requesting a Pageable return value** (you return with a Page object). Spring JPA Data inferns that you are expecting multiple results, and since you asked for a Pagaeble object, the first thing it does is trying to get a total number of records that needs to be "paged".

If you read this part of the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters), you will see, that:

> The first method allows you to pass an
>   org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable instance to the query method
>   to dynamically add paging to your statically defined query. **A Page
>   knows about the total number of elements and pages available. It does
>   so by the infrastructure triggering a count query to calculate the
>   overall number.**

In case you expected some Clients to be returned, then you still need to figure out why `count` returns with 0, meaning that it did not find your `Clients` by that userId. But that is a different question.

Comment: what are the changes I need to make to get clients  instead count(*)?

Comment: As I said, that is a quite different question. We would surely need at least your JPA mapping objects.

Comment: I have edited the question with UserAssignedClients.java file. is it sufficient or  shall I need to provide any further details?

Comment: Well, it is debugging from here. We will see what is needed later. First thing: can you explain how your own log message indicates that you are getting 10 records back? *Returned userAssignedCustomersList Size 10*

Comment: Gergely, unfortunately my system was crashed and I am facing problem to replicate the scenario, will update here if I get back to this case.